# C String Length using null

Tags: c, string

I know the C language has dynamic length strings whereby it uses the special character null (represented as 0) to terminate a string - rather than maintaining the length.
I have this simple C code that creates a string with the null character in the fifth index:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main () {   
  char * s= "sdfsd\0sfdfsd";
  printf("%s",s);
  s[5]='3';
  printf("%s",s);
  return 0;
}
```

Thus, a print of the string will only output up to the fifth index.  Then the code changes the character at the fifth index to a '3'.  Given my understanding, I assumed it would print the full string with the 3 instead of the null, as such:
sdfsdsdfsd3sfdfsd

but instead it outputs:
sdfsdsdfsd

Can someone explain this?

Comment: String literals cannot be changed, an attempt to do so creares undefined behaviour.

Comment: Try `char *s = (char[]){ "sdfsd\0sfdfsd" };` (using a *compound literal* to initialize `s` as a *pointer to array of char*) or `char s[] = "sdfsd\0sfdfsd";` to initialize as an array of char.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char \*s" but not "char s\[\]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals can not be changed because the **compiler put the string literals into a read-only data-section** (but this might vary by underlying platform). The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined.

In your code:

```
char * s= "sdfsd\0sfdfsd"
```

Here, `s` is char pointer pointing to a string `"sdfsd\0sfdfsd"` stored in read-only memory, making it immutable.

Here you are trying to modify the content of read-only memory:

```
s[5]='3';
```

which leads to undefined behavior.

Instead, you can use char[]:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  char a[] = "sdfsd\0sfdfsd";
  char * s = a;
  printf("%s",s);
  s[5]='3';
  printf("%s\n",s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it's the other way around. The compiler *may* put string literals in a read-only data section *because* they cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2):

This program exhibits undefined behavior because you modify a read-only string literal. `char* s = "..."` makes `s` point to *constant memory*; C++ actually disallows pointing non-const `char*` to string literals, but in C it's still possible, and we have to be careful (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30662565/8206) for more details and a C99 standards quote)

Change the assignment line to:

```
char s[] = "sdfsd\0sfdfsd";
```

Which creates an array on the stack and copies the string to it, as an initializer. In this case modifying `s[5]` is valid and you get the result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

This operation has failed:

```
s[5] = 3;
```

You're trying to change a **string literal**, which is always read-only. My testing shows the program exited with segfault:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

You should store it in an array (or allocated memory) before any attempts to change it:

```
char s[] = "sdfsd\0sfdfsd";
```

With the above change, the program works as intended.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char x[10] = "aa\0a";
    x[2] = '1';
    puts(x);

    printf("\n\n\nPress any key to exit...");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `aa1a`

Comment: Please format your code and add necessary text explanation.